# vsftpd will not start - no error messages

Tags: centos7, vsftpd

I'm trying to install and run vsftpd on a CentOS 7 server, but I'm running into the following problem.  I ran `yum install vsftpd` but I can't start it:

```
$ systemctl start vsftpd
Job for vsftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vsftpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-10 21:21:56 UTC; 12s ago
  Process: 27650 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
$ journalctl -xe | grep vsftpd
May 10 21:12:59 s198-12-156-35.secureserver.net yum[27519]: Installed: vsftpd-3.0.2-22.el7.x86_64
```

As you can see, there's not much to go off of.  Any other places I should look for relevant logging output?  Should I post my configuration as well? (I haven't changed it or touched it since installing vsftpd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer asking on #centos on Freenode.  In my case, my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file contained

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
```

and I needed to change it to

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Apparently that was not the default for vsftpd - somebody had changed it either in the centos repo, or otherwise between upstream and my machine.

BTW It would have been nice if there were at least an error message saying that it could not bind to an ipv6 address - then I wouldn't have had to wonder.  I will send a feature request to the vsftpd people at my earliest convenience.